# multiple arguments with PySide QtCore.Slot decorator

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyside

How do you define multiple arguments? What types are supported? And why does it sometimes fail when I combine it with another decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find real documentation on this so I went to the source -- [pysideslot.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside/blobs/ec45601aa14400b3d3e13f3f326e57d534da6ad2/libpyside/pysideslot.cpp).

`Slot` takes two keyword args, `name` (a string to name the slot) and `result` (a python type object or string naming a Qt type, used to specify the return type of the function). If `name` isn't supplied, it will try to read it from the function you're decorating, but be careful: other decorators will sometimes ruin the name of your function, so if you're combining Slot with another decorator you may want to explicitly specify the `name` arg.

Any positional arguments you feed to Slot will get converted to strings by PySide::Signal::getTypeName and then joined into a comma-separated string. This will become the signature of the slot and is used for routing calls.

For example, given this decorator:

```
@QtCore.Slot(int,str,result=float)
def func(a,b):
  assert len(b)==a; upload(b); return 2.5
```

The PySide internals will create a call signature string of 'int,QString' and a resultType string of 'double'.

I hope this helps the next person struggling to debug their slots.